# BindingProxy: binding to the indexed property

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, propertychanged

I have a BindingProxy to Bind the Visibility-Property of DataGridColumns of a DataGrid to a Value in a Dictionary ("ColumnsVisibility"). I Also have a Context-Menu, that should make it possible to hide/show the columns of the Grid.

```
<DataGrid Name="dgMachines"
          ItemsSource="{Binding HVMachineList,
          UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"                  
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          >
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <local:BindingProxy x:Key="proxy" Data="{Binding}"/>
        <ContextMenu x:Key="DataGridColumnHeaderContextMenu">
            <MenuItem Header="Names">
                <CheckBox Content="Name" IsChecked="{Binding Data.ColumnsVisibility[ElementName], Source={StaticResource proxy}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            </MenuItem>
        </ContextMenu>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding ElementName}" Visibility="{Binding Data.ColumnsVisibility[ElementName], UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Source={StaticResource proxy}, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConv},  Mode=TwoWay}" />                
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The initial loading works, if the Dictionary "ColumnsVisibility" is filled with Information before InitializeComponent(), the value I set the DictionaryEntry to, is applied.

My target is to check the checkbox in the Contextmenu and the Column appears/disappears. Because the ContextMenu and the Columns are not Member of the same visual tree as the DataGrid or everything else, I'm using the Proxy.
My problem is, that the checking/unchecking of the CheckBox in the ContextMenu don't change the value of ColumnsVisibility[ElementName]. If I add a check/uncheck-Event to the Checkbox, I can change it by using it in the code, but triggering a PropertyChanged-Event don't change anything visual. The column stays as it is.

Is the BindingProxy forwarding Events to the GUI and vice versa? Currently it seems like it doesn't.
Anybody has an Idea how to solve this problem?

**EDIT:**
The BindingProxy:

```
public class BindingProxy : Freezable
{
    #region Overrides of Freezable

    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    {
        return new BindingProxy();
    }

    #endregion

    public object Data
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(DataProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Data.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(object), typeof(BindingProxy), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

**Edit2:**
The ColumnsVisibilty Property

```
private Dictionary<string, bool> _ColumnsVisibility = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
public Dictionary<string, bool> ColumnsVisibility
    {
        get{return(_ColumnsVisibility);}
        set
        {   
            _ColumnsVisibility = value;

            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ColumnsVisibility"));
        }
    }
```

Before InitializeComponent() this is done on loading:

```
_ColumnsVisibility.Add("ElementName", false);
```

**Edit3**
OK, here is the full sourcecode:
Interaction logic:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Security;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace HyperV
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for HyperVControl.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class HyperVControl : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public HyperVControl()
    {            
        #region Set default visibility for Columns
        _ColumnsVisibility.Add("ElementName", false);
        //(...)
        #endregion

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    #region Control triggered
    private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Is Triggered by Checkboxes, that are in the contextmenu of the DataGrid-Header to show/hide columns
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The Checkbox, that send this command</param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //This sets the value in ColumnsVisibility to be sure. The value is NOT set by binding (but should...)
        ColumnsVisibility[((CheckBox)sender).Tag.ToString()] = (bool)((CheckBox)sender).IsChecked;

        //Nothing of this works
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ColumnsVisibility"));
            PropertyChanged(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ColumnsVisibility[Machinename]"));
            PropertyChanged(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Data.ColumnsVisibility"));
            PropertyChanged(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Data.ColumnsVisibility[Machinename]"));
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Properties (private and publics)      
    private ObservableCollection<HyperVMachine> _HVMachineList;       
    private Dictionary<string, bool> _ColumnsVisibility = new Dictionary<string, bool>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Contains all loaded information about the virtual Clients
    /// </summary>
    public ObservableCollection<HyperVMachine> HVMachineList
    {
        get { return _HVMachineList; }
        set 
        {
            _HVMachineList = value;

            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("HVMachineList"));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// To set 
    /// </summary>
    public Dictionary<string, bool> ColumnsVisibility
    {
        get{return(_ColumnsVisibility);}
        set
        {   
            _ColumnsVisibility = value;

            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ColumnsVisibility"));
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Events
    //To Update Content on the Form
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;        
    #endregion
}

//Binding Proxy
#region Freezable for Context-Menu-Data-Transmition
public class BindingProxy : Freezable
{
    #region Overrides of Freezable

    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    {
        return new BindingProxy();
    }

    #endregion

    public object Data
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(DataProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Data.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(object), typeof(BindingProxy), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
}
#endregion
}
```

XAML:

```
<UserControl xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:HyperV.Controls"  
         x:Class="HyperV.HyperVControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HyperV"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="900"
         Loaded="UserControl_Loaded"
         DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}"             
         >
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Language/language.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Language/language.de-DE.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        <local:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibilityConv"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <DataGrid Name="dgMachines"
              ItemsSource="{Binding HVMachineList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"                  
              >
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <local:BindingProxy x:Key="proxy" Data="{Binding}"/>
            <ContextMenu x:Key="DataGridColumnHeaderContextMenu">
                <MenuItem Header="{StaticResource MenHeadGeneral}">
                    <CheckBox Tag="ElementName" Content="{StaticResource MenMachinename}" IsChecked="{Binding Data.ColumnsVisibility[ElementName], Source={StaticResource proxy}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Checked="CheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="CheckBox_Checked"/>                        
                    <!-- ... -->
                </MenuItem>
                <!-- ... -->
            </ContextMenu>

            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource DataGridColumnHeaderContextMenu}" />
            </Style>


        </DataGrid.Resources>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="{StaticResource MenMachinename}" Binding="{Binding ElementName}" Visibility="{Binding Data.ColumnsVisibility[ElementName], UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Source={StaticResource proxy}, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConv},  Mode=TwoWay}" />                
            <!-- ... -->
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Can you show the data model that is bound to BindingProxy?

Comment: Hi Eugene, I added it it the original Post

Comment: I meant the DataSource of your window: local:BindingProxy x:Key="proxy" Data="{Binding}"

Comment: And have you tried to create the checkBox in the visual tree(binding it through BindingProxy)? It is just to see whether the issue has something to do with ContextMenu or not.

Comment: Hi, there is no special DataSource. It binds to the parent. So I can access everything by Data.whatever (in this case Data.ColumnsVisibility). I added ColumnsVisibility to the original post. If I change the value i.e. by using a button and trigger PropertyChanged, the grid don't react on this

Comment: Well, what is the parent's DataSource? What is the data object that contains ColumnsVisibility property? Can you show its definition? I mean something like ColumnVisibilityCollection ColumnsVisibility { get; private set;} in MainViewModel class.

Comment: OK, to make everything easier: see Edit3 - I added the full code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

It is an error for sure:

`PropertyChanged(`**null**`, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ColumnsVisibility"));`

It should be:

`PropertyChanged(`**this**`, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ColumnsVisibility"));`

I have blindly copied it into my first edit from your code. Well, sometimes you just don't see the things before your eyes

For future I recommend you to use some sort of a function in some base class like

```
public class NotifyPropertyChangeableBase: INotifyPropertyChanged // Usually I name it somewhat like 'ViewModelBase' in my projects, but your actual class is the control, so it is not the most appropriate name
{
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(this,
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

It did not solve the issue, but it is at least one problem down

**EDIT WITH(I HOPE) THE FINAL SOLUTION:**

It looks that you cannot notify the WPF engine that your dictionary has changed its items. And standard Dictionary does not do it on its own(it does not implement the ICollectionChanged or even INotifyPropertyChanged).

That's why you have to use your own dictionary, or to be more precise wrapper dictionary class:

```
public class DictionaryNotificationWrapper<TKey, TValue> : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region Fields

    private IDictionary<TKey, TValue> innerDictionary;

    #endregion



    #region Constructors

    public DictionaryNotificationWrapper(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> innerDictionary)
    {
        if (innerDictionary == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("innerDictionary", "The inner dictionary is null");

        this.innerDictionary = innerDictionary;
    }

    #endregion



    #region IDictionary implementation

    public TValue this[TKey key]
    {
        get
        {
            return this.innerDictionary[key];
        }
        set
        {
            this.innerDictionary[key] = value;

            this.OnPropertyChanged("Item[]");
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Count");
        }
    }

    #endregion



    #region not implemented IDictionary members - you are free to finish the work

    public void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool ContainsKey(TKey key)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public ICollection<TKey> Keys
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public bool Remove(TKey key)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool TryGetValue(TKey key, out TValue value)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public ICollection<TValue> Values
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }


    public void Add(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool Contains(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void CopyTo(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public bool Remove(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion



    #region INotifyPropertyChanged implementation


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


    protected void OnPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(this,
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion
}
```

With such a class:

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for HyperVControl.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class HyperVControl : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region Constructors

    public HyperVControl()
    {
        // Form initialization
        InitializeComponent();

        // Initialize columns visibility collection
        IDictionary<String, Boolean> innerColumnsVisibilityDictionary = new Dictionary<String, Boolean>();
        innerColumnsVisibilityDictionary.Add("ElementName", true);
        // Wrap the visibility dictionary
        this.ColumnsVisibility = new DictionaryNotificationWrapper<String, Boolean>(innerColumnsVisibilityDictionary);

        // Initialize grid's datasource
        this.HVMachineList = new ObservableCollection<HyperVMachine>();
        this.HVMachineList.Add(new HyperVMachine());
        this.HVMachineList.Add(new HyperVMachine());
        this.HVMachineList.Add(new HyperVMachine());
    }
```

you will be able to notify your visual components without any code-behind.

P.S.: I have implemented INotifyProperyChanged that notifies about the changes in Item[] indexed property, but you could try to implement INotifyCollectionChanged interface - I am just unsure how it will work with indexed bindings.
P.P.S.: I haven't seen your comment that you have found `this.PropertyChanged(`**this**`, new ...` issue.
P.P.P.S.: If you have time then change the question title to "BindingProxy: binding to the indexed property" to better reflect the problem and leave only the code from the last edit(to avoid duplication) - think of it as the community service.

Comment: This isn't working too. I also tried Values, Values[], Keys, Keys[], Item[MachineName], Values[Machinename], Keys[Machinename], Value, Value[], Value[Machinename]. I still thing the whole communication (both ways) don't work. The Value is set because I handle it by using the checked/unchecked event. If it works as I expect, it should be set by the binding.

Comment: I tested it with a boolean instead of the dictionary. This doesn't work too but the bool is set by the CheckBox! Only the change of the visibility of the column doesn't work

Comment: You mean with a simple Bool property?

Comment: I edited my post before because it was not completely correct. Yes I mean a simple bool property => public bool Testbool{get;set;}

Comment: Like in my last edit? Let's also try to change BindingMode like I've shown.

Comment: Yes, like your edit. I recognized, that the BoolToVis-Converter was called. So something is going on there. With the OneWay-Option for the Column it works :). In the Check/Uncheck-Command I just have to call the PropertyChanged. AND FINALLY: This way it works with the dictionary too! The correct PropertyChanged-Call is this: PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ColumnsVisibility"));