# WPF user control not updating path

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, user-controls

I have a stripped down WPF example of a problem I am having in a much larger project.  I have a user control called "UserControl1".  The data context is set to self so I have dependency properties defined in the code-behind.

In the control I have an ItemsControl. In the ItemsSource I have a CompositeCollection that contains a CollectionContainer and a Line.  The Line is there just to prove to myself that I am drawing.

I also have an object called "GraphPen" that contains a PathGeometry dependency property.  The CollectionContainer of the user control contains an ObservableCollection of these GraphPens.

Now, I have a "MainWindow" to test the user control.  In the MainWindow I have a DispatchTimer and in the Tick event of that timer, I add LineSegments to a PathFigure which has been added to the Figures collection of the PathGeometry of the single instance of the GraphPen.

I expect to see a diagonal line being drawn in parallel to the existing red line, but nothing shows up.  If I put a break point at the end of the Tick event handler, I can examine the user control and drill down and see that the line segments do exist.  For some reason they are not being rendered.  I suspect I have done something wrong in the binding.

I will supply the code below.

GraphPen.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace WpfExampleControlLibrary
{
    public class GraphPen : DependencyObject
    {
        #region Constructor

        public GraphPen()
        {
            PenGeometry = new PathGeometry();
        }

        #endregion Constructor

        #region Dependency Properties

        // Line Color

        public static PropertyMetadata PenLineColorPropertyMetadata
            = new PropertyMetadata(null);
        public static DependencyProperty PenLineColorProperty
            = DependencyProperty.Register(
                "PenLineColor",
                typeof(Brush),
                typeof(GraphPen),
                PenLineColorPropertyMetadata);
        public Brush PenLineColor
        {
            get { return (Brush)GetValue(PenLineColorProperty); }
            set { SetValue(PenLineColorProperty, value); }
        }

        // Line Thickness

        public static PropertyMetadata PenLineThicknessPropertyMetadata
            = new PropertyMetadata(null);
        public static DependencyProperty PenLineThicknessProperty
            = DependencyProperty.Register(
                "PenLineThickness",
                typeof(Int32),
                typeof(GraphPen),
                PenLineThicknessPropertyMetadata);
        public Int32 PenLineThickness
        {
            get { return (Int32)GetValue(PenLineThicknessProperty); }
            set { SetValue(PenLineThicknessProperty, value); }
        }

        // Pen Geometry

        public static PropertyMetadata PenGeometryMetadata = new PropertyMetadata(null);
        public static DependencyProperty PenGeometryProperty
            = DependencyProperty.Register(
                "PenGeometry",
                typeof(PathGeometry),
                typeof(UserControl1),
                PenGeometryMetadata);

        public PathGeometry PenGeometry
        {
            get { return (PathGeometry)GetValue(PenGeometryProperty); }
            set { SetValue(PenGeometryProperty, value); }
        }

        #endregion Dependency Properties
    }
}
```

UserControl1.xaml

```
<UserControl Name="ExampleControl"
             x:Class="WpfExampleControlLibrary.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfExampleControlLibrary"
             DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UserControl.Resources>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:GraphPen}">
            <Path Stroke="{Binding Path=PenLineColor}"
                  StrokeThickness="{Binding Path=PenLineThickness}"
                  Data="{Binding Path=Geometry}">
            </Path>
        </DataTemplate>

    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ItemsControl Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas Background="Aquamarine">
                        <Canvas.LayoutTransform>
                            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="-1" CenterX=".5" CenterY=".5"/>
                        </Canvas.LayoutTransform>
                    </Canvas>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
                <CompositeCollection>
                    <CollectionContainer
                        Collection="{
                            Binding Source={RelativeSource Self}, 
                            Path=GraphPens,
                            Mode=OneWay}"/>
                    <Line X1="10" Y1="0" X2="200" Y2="180" Stroke="DarkRed" StrokeThickness="2"/>
                </CompositeCollection>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
        </ItemsControl>
        <TextBox x:Name="debug" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Path=DebugText}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

UserControl1.xaml.cs

```
namespace WpfExampleControlLibrary
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for UserControl1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            GraphPens = new ObservableCollection<GraphPen>();
        }

        #region Dependency Properties

        // Pens

        public static PropertyMetadata GraphPenMetadata = new PropertyMetadata(null);
        public static DependencyProperty GraphPensProperty
            = DependencyProperty.Register(
                "GraphPens",
                typeof(ObservableCollection<GraphPen>),
                typeof(UserControl1),
                GraphPenMetadata);

        public ObservableCollection<GraphPen> GraphPens
        {
            get { return (ObservableCollection<GraphPen>)GetValue(GraphPensProperty); }
            set { SetValue(GraphPensProperty, value); }
        }

        // Debug Text

        public static PropertyMetadata DebugTextMetadata = new PropertyMetadata(null);
        public static DependencyProperty DebugTextProperty
            = DependencyProperty.Register(
                "DebugText",
                typeof(string),
                typeof(UserControl1),
                DebugTextMetadata);

        public string DebugText
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(DebugTextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DebugTextProperty, value); }
        }

        #endregion Dependency Properties
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="POC_WPF_UserControlExample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:Exmpl="clr-namespace:WpfExampleControlLibrary;assembly=WpfExampleControlLibrary"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:POC_WPF_UserControlExample"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="550" Width="550">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="100" />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition Height="100" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Exmpl:UserControl1 Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="myExample"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
namespace POC_WPF_UserControlExample
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private DispatcherTimer _timer = null;
        private GraphPen _graphPen0 = null;
        private Int32 _pos = 0;
        private PathFigure _pathFigure = null;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _graphPen0 = new GraphPen();
            _graphPen0.PenLineColor = Brushes.DarkGoldenrod;
            _graphPen0.PenLineThickness = 2;
            myExample.GraphPens.Add(_graphPen0);

            _timer = new DispatcherTimer();
            _timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
            _timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 100);
            _timer.Start();
        }

        private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _pos++;
            Point penPoint0 = new Point(_pos, _pos + 20);
            if (_graphPen0.PenGeometry.Figures.Count == 0)
            {
                _pathFigure = new PathFigure();
                _graphPen0.PenGeometry.Figures.Add(_pathFigure);
                _pathFigure.StartPoint = penPoint0;
            }
            else
            {
                LineSegment segment = new LineSegment(penPoint0, false);
                _pathFigure.Segments.Add(segment);
            }
            myExample.DebugText = _pos.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Screen Shot

[image: The line being drawn should be parallel to the red line]

Comment: Did you try replacing the GraphPen instead of altering the existing one?

Comment: Ed, Thanks for the quick reply.  Just tried it, but no joy.  In a way I'm glad that wasn't the answer.  In the big project I will have dozens of Pens updating their lines about once every 10 milliseconds.  I would hate the overhead of having to recreate the pens each time.  I would think the ObservableCollection would take care of this for me.

Comment: ObservableCollection raises events when you add or remove items from it. It has no clue what's going on in the properties of the items it contains. The key things here are [`_graphPen0.PenGeometry.Figures.Add(_pathFigure);`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.pathfigurecollection(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`_pathFigure.Segments.Add(segment);`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.pathsegmentcollection(v=vs.110).aspx). I don't think either one of those collections is raising any events when you change their contents.

Comment: I wrote a little WPF drawing thing once, and I created a new `PathGeometry` each time I added to the Path. On your scale, you can't afford to be recreating everything every 10 msec, but I think you want an ObservableCollection of completed path figures, and a path figure in progress that you replace each time it changes. When it's complete, add it to the collection.

Comment: Ed,  Again, thanks for the quick reply.  The ObservableCollection only raising events when the count changes makes sense.  Now the ObservableCollection is inside a DependencyProperty, but if the only event is count changed, if the content changes it won't be passed up.  Do you think the INotifyPropertyChanged pattern will work?  I could then manually trigger the change?

Comment: `INotifyPropertyChanged` should work. `GraphPen` would raise `PropertyChanged` for `PenGeometry` when you add a new figure to `PenGeometry.Figures`, or change one of the existing items in `PenGeometry.Figures`.

Comment: Ok, INotifyPropertyChanged did not work either.  I've been trying things randomly all day.  I wish there were some way to debug xaml other than trying random changes. (note frustration tone)  I'm out of ideas.

Comment: I understand your frustration. This stuff can be painful even when you know your way around it. I've copied your code, and was able to identify/fix one problem: Your binding to GraphPens in UserControl1 wasn't working. The solution is complicated; I had to use a [BindingProxy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24452264/propertychanged-and-bindingproxy). I still don't have it updating the drawing, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not need `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and I did not need to recreate `PenGeometry`. I'm sorry I wasted your time with those ideas.

I've got your code drawing... something. A line that grows. I don't know if it's drawing exactly what you want, but you can figure out that part now that you can see what it *is* drawing.

First, minor copy/paste error in `GraphPen.cs`:

```
    public static DependencyProperty PenGeometryProperty
        = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "PenGeometry",
            typeof(PathGeometry),
            typeof(UserControl1),
            PenGeometryMetadata);
```

Owner type parameter needs to be `GraphPen`, not `UserControl1`:

```
            typeof(PathGeometry),
            typeof(GraphPen),
            PenGeometryMetadata);
```

Second: Binding in `UserControl1`. Your binding to `Self` isn't going to work because `Self`, in that case, is the `CollectionContainer` you're binding on. Usually you'd use a source of `RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}`, but `CollectionContainer` is not in the visual tree so that doesn't work (real intuitive, huh?). Instead we use a `BindingProxy` (source to follow):

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <!-- ... stuff ... -->

    <local:BindingProxy 
        x:Key="UserControlBindingProxy"
        Data="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" 
        />
</UserControl.Resources>
```

And for the collection container...

```
<CollectionContainer
    Collection="{
        Binding 
        Source={StaticResource UserControlBindingProxy},
        Path=Data.GraphPens,
        Mode=OneWay}"
    />
```

Notice we're binding to `Data.GraphPens`; `Data` is the target of the proxy.

Also, we need an `ItemTemplate` for the `ItemsControl`, because it doesn't know how to display a `GraphPen`:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="local:GraphPen">
        <Border >
            <Path
                Data="{Binding PenGeometry}"
                StrokeThickness="{Binding PenLineThickness}"
                Stroke="{Binding PenLineColor, PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=None}"
                />
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Note `PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=None`. Change `None` to `High` and it'll give you a lot of debugging info about the `Binding` in the VS Output pane. I added that when I was trying to figure out why I was setting `PenLineColor` to `Brushes.Black` in the constructor, but it kept coming out `DarkGoldenrod` at runtime. Can you say *duhhh?* Duhhh!

Now the binding proxy. What that does is you take any random object you want to use as a `DataContext`, bind it to `Data` on a `BindingProxy` instance defined as a resource, and you've got that `DataContext` available via a resource that you can get to with a `StaticResource`. If you're someplace where you can't get to something via the visual tree with `RelativeSource`, it's an option that you can rely on.

BindingProxy.cs

```
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfExampleControlLibrary
{
    public class BindingProxy : Freezable
    {
        #region Overrides of Freezable

        protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
        {
            return new BindingProxy();
        }

        #endregion

        public object Data
        {
            get { return (object)GetValue(DataProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Data.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(object), typeof(BindingProxy), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
    }
}
```

And finally, in MainWindow, you need to pass `true` for `isStroked` on the `LineSegment` instances:

```
LineSegment segment = new LineSegment(penPoint0, true);
```

Otherwise they're not drawn.

So now it's back in your lap, in warm goldenrod and soothing aquamarine. *Ave, imperator*, and all that.

**Edit by original author!**

Thank you Ed for all your effort.

1. I can't believe I missed the UserControl1 -> GraphPen
2. The BindingProxy will be very handy
3. The TraceLevel will also be handy, I had not used that before
4. I also corrected the DebugText binding and now that works

   > I never even noticed that!
5. In the DataTemplate why did we need to wrap the Path in a Border?

   > We don't. Before I got the `Path` showing, I added that to have something in the template that was guaranteed to be visible . It had a green border originally. I removed those attributes, but forgot to remove the `Border` itself.
6. If you look in my Timer_Tick you will note that now all I have to update is adding new segments.  Hopefully, this will help performance.  Your opinion?

   > No idea. I would actually put that segment adding code in `GraphPen` as `AddSegment(Point pt)` and `AddSegment(float x, float y) => AddSegment(new Point(x,y));` overloads. I have a great allergy to putting logic in event handlers. The most I'll do is toss an `if` or a `try/catch` around a non-handler method that does the real work. Then I'd write `AddSegment(Point pt)` both ways and benchmark one against the other.

I will add my code for completeness:

UserControl1.xaml

```
<UserControl Name="ExampleControl"
             x:Class="WpfExampleControlLibrary.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfExampleControlLibrary"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UserControl.Resources>

        <local:BindingProxy
            x:Key="UserControlBindingProxy"
            Data="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:GraphPen}">
            <Border>
                <Path
                    Data="{Binding PenGeometry}"
                    StrokeThickness="{Binding PenLineThickness}"
                    Stroke="{Binding
                        PenLineColor,
                        PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=None}"
                    />
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>

    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ItemsControl Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas Background="Aquamarine">
                        <Canvas.LayoutTransform>
                            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="-1" CenterX=".5" CenterY=".5"/>
                        </Canvas.LayoutTransform>
                    </Canvas>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
                <CompositeCollection>
                    <CollectionContainer
                        Collection="{Binding
                            Source={StaticResource UserControlBindingProxy}, 
                            Path=Data.GraphPens,
                            Mode=OneWay}"/>
                    <Line X1="10" Y1="0" X2="200" Y2="180" Stroke="DarkRed" StrokeThickness="2"/>
                </CompositeCollection>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
        </ItemsControl>
        <TextBox
            x:Name="debug"
            Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"
            Text="{Binding
                Source={StaticResource UserControlBindingProxy},
                Path=Data.DebugText,
                Mode=OneWay}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

UserControl1.xaml.cs

```
namespace WpfExampleControlLibrary
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for UserControl1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        #region Constructor

        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            GraphPens = new ObservableCollection<GraphPen>();
        }

        #endregion Constructor

        #region Public Methods

        #endregion Public Methods

        #region Dependency Properties

        // Pens

        public static PropertyMetadata GraphPenMetadata = new PropertyMetadata(null);
        public static DependencyProperty GraphPensProperty
            = DependencyProperty.Register(
                "GraphPens",
                typeof(ObservableCollection<GraphPen>),
                typeof(UserControl1),
                GraphPenMetadata);

        public ObservableCollection<GraphPen> GraphPens
        {
            get { return (ObservableCollection<GraphPen>)GetValue(GraphPensProperty); }
            set { SetValue(GraphPensProperty, value); }
        }

        // Debug Text

        public static PropertyMetadata DebugTextMetadata = new PropertyMetadata(null);
        public static DependencyProperty DebugTextProperty
            = DependencyProperty.Register(
                "DebugText",
                typeof(string),
                typeof(UserControl1),
                DebugTextMetadata);

        public string DebugText
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(DebugTextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DebugTextProperty, value); }
        }

        #endregion Dependency Properties
    }
}
```

GraphPen.cs

```
namespace WpfExampleControlLibrary
{
    public class GraphPen : DependencyObject
    {
        #region Constructor

        public GraphPen()
        {
            PenGeometry = new PathGeometry();
        }

        #endregion Constructor

        #region Dependency Properties

        // Line Color

        public static PropertyMetadata PenLineColorPropertyMetadata
            = new PropertyMetadata(null);
        public static DependencyProperty PenLineColorProperty
            = DependencyProperty.Register(
                "PenLineColor",
                typeof(Brush),
                typeof(GraphPen),
                PenLineColorPropertyMetadata);
        public Brush PenLineColor
        {
            get { return (Brush)GetValue(PenLineColorProperty); }
            set { SetValue(PenLineColorProperty, value); }
        }

        // Line Thickness

        public static PropertyMetadata PenLineThicknessPropertyMetadata
            = new PropertyMetadata(null);
        public static DependencyProperty PenLineThicknessProperty
            = DependencyProperty.Register(
                "PenLineThickness",
                typeof(Int32),
                typeof(GraphPen),
                PenLineThicknessPropertyMetadata);
        public Int32 PenLineThickness
        {
            get { return (Int32)GetValue(PenLineThicknessProperty); }
            set { SetValue(PenLineThicknessProperty, value); }
        }

        // Pen Geometry

        public static PropertyMetadata PenGeometryMetadata = new PropertyMetadata(null);
        public static DependencyProperty PenGeometryProperty
            = DependencyProperty.Register(
                "PenGeometry",
                typeof(PathGeometry),
                typeof(GraphPen),
                PenGeometryMetadata);

        public PathGeometry PenGeometry
        {
            get { return (PathGeometry)GetValue(PenGeometryProperty); }
            set { SetValue(PenGeometryProperty, value); }
        }

        #endregion Dependency Properties
    }
}
```

BindingProxy.cs

```
namespace WpfExampleControlLibrary
{
    public class BindingProxy : Freezable
    {
        #region Override Freezable Abstract Parts
        protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
        {
            return new BindingProxy();
        }

        #endregion Override Freezable Abstract Parts

        #region Dependency Properties

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Data.
        // This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static PropertyMetadata DataMetadata = new PropertyMetadata(null);
        public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty
            = DependencyProperty.Register(
                "Data",
                typeof(object),
                typeof(BindingProxy),
                DataMetadata);

        public object Data
        {
            get { return (object)GetValue(DataProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
        }

        #endregion Dependency Properties
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="POC_WPF_UserControlExample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:Exmpl="clr-namespace:WpfExampleControlLibrary;assembly=WpfExampleControlLibrary"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:POC_WPF_UserControlExample"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="550" Width="550">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="100" />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition Height="100" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Exmpl:UserControl1 Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="myExample"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
namespace POC_WPF_UserControlExample
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private DispatcherTimer _timer = null;
        private GraphPen _graphPen0 = null;
        private Int32 _pos = 0;
        private PathFigure _pathFigure0 = null;
        private bool _firstTime = true;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _pathFigure0 = new PathFigure();
            _graphPen0 = new GraphPen();
            _graphPen0.PenLineColor = Brushes.DarkGoldenrod;
            _graphPen0.PenLineThickness = 2;
            _graphPen0.PenGeometry = new PathGeometry();
            _graphPen0.PenGeometry.Figures.Add(_pathFigure0);
            myExample.GraphPens.Add(_graphPen0);

            _timer = new DispatcherTimer();
            _timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
            _timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 100);
            _timer.Start();
        }

        private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _pos++;
            Point penPoint0 = new Point(_pos, _pos + 20);
            if (_firstTime)
            {
                myExample.GraphPens[0].PenGeometry.Figures[0].StartPoint = penPoint0;
                _firstTime = false;
            }
            else
            {
                LineSegment segment = new LineSegment(penPoint0, true);
                myExample.GraphPens[0].PenGeometry.Figures[0].Segments.Add(segment);
            }

            myExample.DebugText = _pos.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ed,  You are a prince.  I have to leave today, but I'll jump on this tomorrow.  Thanks again.  I'll update this when I get done.

Comment: Ed,  See my edits to your answer.  They should show up after they've been reviewed. - Doug

Comment: Ed,  I'm definitely going to look at your approach to getting the code out  of the event handler.  I share your allergy.  Thanks again for all your help.