# Binding to a Dependency Property inside UserControl XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, dependency-properties

I want to reuse a control, but one of the scenarios requires a context menu and the others do not. Here's my attempt.

```
public partial class RP8Grid : UserControl {

    public bool UseContextMenu {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(UseContextMenuProperty); }
        set { SetValue(UseContextMenuProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for UseContextMenu.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty UseContextMenuProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("UseContextMenu", typeof(bool), typeof(RP8Grid), new PropertyMetadata(false));

        public RP8Grid() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

And in the XAML to use the Property:

```
<ctls:RP8Grid UseContextMenu="False"/>
```

Now the part I cannot square away, how do I access UseContextMenu inside the UserControl? 
**I Have tried the following:**

```
<DataGrid>
  <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu IsEnabled="{Binding UseContextMenu,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl, Mode=FindAncestor}}">
  </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
</DataGrid>
```

with results:

> Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource
>   FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.UserControl',
>   AncestorLevel='1'

Comment: You are right, I think I hit propa instead of propdp. My first implementation. RelativeSource, then up thru the ancestor chain?

Comment: `<ContextMenu IsEnabled={Binding UseContextMenu, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" />`

Comment: Couldn't find, have updated the question with my attempt

Comment: Right, ContextMenus are out of the visual tree; my bad. I was able to do this with a [binding proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24452264/424129) (that answer illustrates doing something else with one). However, disabling a contextmenu is problematic: It still opens, but with all its items disabled -- and it doesn't close properly. It might be better to give your DataGrid a Style which assigns it the context menu when that property is true.

Comment: Ah, good idea. I'll check out this proxy, thank you.

Comment: The binding proxy worked, but the result was a context menu that wouldn't close. If your goal is simply to make the context menu go away when `UseContextMenu` is false, I'll post that answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what you want is just to get rid of the `ContextMenu` at times, this will work:

```
<DataGrid 
    >
    <DataGrid.Style>
        <Style TargetType="DataGrid" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGrid}}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger 
                    Binding="{Binding UseContextMenu, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
                    Value="True"
                    >
                    <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ContextMenu 
                                >
                                <MenuItem Header="Test Item" />
                                <MenuItem Header="Test Item" />
                                <MenuItem Header="Test Item" />
                                <MenuItem Header="Test Item" />
                            </ContextMenu>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Style>
</DataGrid>
```