# C# - Popup is not displayed in second tab item in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, tabitem

I'm working in MVVM and i have two `TabItem` created in XAML. In the first one, the popup is displayed, but in the second one when I press the button corresponding to a column, the popup is not displayed.

Here is my code with the working Popup:

```
<Viewbox>
    <Grid Height="359" Width="746">
        <Popup Name="popupFilter" Placement="MousePoint" IsOpen="{Binding IsFilterOpen, Mode=OneWay}" StaysOpen="True" Width="200">
            <Border Background="White" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1">
                <StackPanel Margin="5,5,5,15">
                    <ListBox x:Name="listBoxPopupContent" 
                             Height="250" 
                             ItemsSource="{Binding FilterItems}" 
                             BorderThickness="0" 
                             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" 
                                          Content="{Binding Item}" 
                                          Command="{Binding DataContext.ApplyFiltersCommand, 
                                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                                                AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}"
                                          CommandParameter="{Binding IsChecked, 
                                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
                                                Mode=OneWay}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </Popup>

        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="261" Margin="0,63,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="736">
            <TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="175" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="716" Margin="10,0,0,0">
                <TabItem Header="Class">
                    <DataGrid x:Name="ClassViewDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredClassViewItems}" 
                              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                              IsReadOnly="True"
                              CanUserReorderColumns="True"
                              CanUserResizeColumns="True"
                              CanUserSortColumns="True">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ClassName}">
                                <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <TextBlock Text="Class" />
                                        <Button Name="buttonClassViewClassFilter" Margin="10,0,0,0"                          
                                                Command="{Binding DataContext.ShowFilterCommand, 
                                                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                                                    AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"
                                                CommandParameter="{Binding Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                                            <Button.ContentTemplate>
                                                <DataTemplate>
                                                    <Image Source="/Images/filter.png" Width="10" Height="10" />
                                                </DataTemplate>
                                            </Button.ContentTemplate>
                                        </Button>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
```

and the tabItem that doesn't shows the popup:

```
<TabItem Header="Field">
    <DataGrid x:Name="FielsdViewDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredFieldViewItems}" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              IsReadOnly="True"
              CanUserReorderColumns="True"
              CanUserResizeColumns="True"
              CanUserSortColumns="True">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ClassName}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="Class" />
                        <Button Name="buttonFieldViewClassFilter" Margin="10,0,0,0"                          
                                Command="{Binding DataContext.ShowFilterCommand, 
                                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                                    AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                            <Button.ContentTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Image Source="/Images/filter.png" Width="10" Height="10" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </Button.ContentTemplate>
                        </Button>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
```

...

The second `tabItem` is defined like the first one, but it seems that the `Binding DataContext.ShowFilterCommand` is not reached. I tried to enter with debug there but is not reached.

Here is the method:

```
private void ShowFilterCommandRaised(object obj)
{
    IsFilterOpen = !IsFilterOpen;
    str = obj;
    if (IsFilterOpen)
    {
        if (str.Equals("buttonClassViewClassFilter"))
        {
            FilterItems.Clear();
            foreach (var classView in classViewItems)
            {
                FilterItems.Add(new CheckedListItem<string>(classView.ClassName, true));
            }
        }

        if (str.Equals("buttonClassViewExtendsFilter"))
        {
            FilterItems.Clear();
            foreach (var classView in classViewItems)
            {
                FilterItems.Add(new CheckedListItem<string>(classView.Category, true));
            }
        }

        if (str.Equals("buttonFieldViewClassFilter"))
        {
            FilterItems.Clear();
            foreach (var fieldView in fieldViewItems)
            {
                FilterItems.Add(new CheckedListItem<string>(fieldView.ClassName, true));
            }
        }
    }
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Do I correctly understand that you included the XAML for the one that works, rather than the one that doesn't?

Comment: @EdPlunkett , I've included them both now

Comment: Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you swap the order of the two TabItems, or set `SelectedIndex="1"` on the TabControl, you'll find that the one that's initially visible is always the only one that works. I added `PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High` to the `Command` binding, and found that the binding in the TabItem that's hidden on startup tries to resolve its source property initially, and doesn't try again when that TabItem becomes active.

The trouble is that at the time of that first attempt at resolving the binding in the hidden tab item, none of the UI for that TabItem actually exists yet. Due to virtualization, it won't be created until it's needed. All that's created is its Header content, hanging in space. The DataGrid doesn't exist yet, so the AncestorType search never finds it. When the DataGrid is finally created, it seems there is no event that's raised to notify the Binding that it needs to repeat the ancestor search.

The fix for this is easy: Create the header content via a DataTemplate. That's the correct way to do it anyhow. The DataTemplate will be instantiated when the DataGrid is shown.

We'll use a value converter to create an identifier which tells the command what grid and column the user clicked. Notice that we're now giving each column a plain string for its Header property, and the `TextBlock` in the template changes to `<TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />`.

XAML

```
<TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="175" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="716" Margin="10,0,0,0">
    <TabControl.Resources>
        <local:GetColumnIdentifier x:Key="GetColumnIdentifier" />
        
        <DataTemplate x:Key="FilterColumnHeaderTemplate">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                <Button 
                    Margin="10,0,0,0"
                    Command="{Binding DataContext.ShowFilterCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" 
                    CommandParameter="{Binding Converter={StaticResource GetColumnIdentifier}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                    >
                    <Button.ContentTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Image Source="/Images/filter.png" Width="10" Height="10" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Button.ContentTemplate>
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.Resources>
    <TabItem Header="Class">
        <DataGrid 
            x:Name="ClassViewDataGrid" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredClassViewItems}" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            IsReadOnly="True"
            CanUserReorderColumns="True"
            CanUserResizeColumns="True"
            CanUserSortColumns="True"
            >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn 
                    Header="Class"
                    Binding="{Binding ClassName}" 
                    HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource FilterColumnHeaderTemplate}"
                    />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Field">
        <DataGrid 
            x:Name="FielsdViewDataGrid" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredFieldViewItems}" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            IsReadOnly="True"
            CanUserReorderColumns="True"
            CanUserResizeColumns="True"
            CanUserSortColumns="True"
            >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn 
                    Header="Class"
                    Binding="{Binding ClassName}" 
                    HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource FilterColumnHeaderTemplate}"
                    />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

Value converter:

```
//using System.Windows.Markup.Primitives;
//using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;

public class GetColumnIdentifier : IValueConverter
{
    private static T GetVisualAncestor<T>(DependencyObject obj)
        where T : DependencyObject
    {
        while (obj != null)
        {
            if (obj is T)
                return obj as T;
            else
                obj = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(obj);
        }

        return null;
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //  Not all DataGridColumn subclasses have a Binding property. 
        var header = GetVisualAncestor<DataGridColumnHeader>((DependencyObject)value);
        var datagrid = GetVisualAncestor<DataGrid>(header);
        
        if (header?.Column != null)
        {
            MarkupObject markupObject = MarkupWriter.GetMarkupObjectFor(header.Column);
            var bindingProp = markupObject.Properties.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == "Binding");

            if (bindingProp?.Value is Binding binding)
            {
                return $"{datagrid?.Name}.{binding.Path.Path}";
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

---

Here's another solution if you have multiple columns bound to the same path, and you need to distinguish among them (in that case though, you could use the above solution for most of them, but slip in a customized template for the odd special case):

```
<TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="175" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="716" Margin="10,0,0,0">
    <TabItem Header="Class">
        <DataGrid 
            x:Name="ClassViewDataGrid" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredClassViewItems}" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            IsReadOnly="True"
            CanUserReorderColumns="True"
            CanUserResizeColumns="True"
            CanUserSortColumns="True"
            >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn 
                    Header="Class"
                    Binding="{Binding ClassName}" 
                    >
                    <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                                <Button 
                                    Name="buttonClassViewClassFilter" 
                                    Margin="10,0,0,0"
                                    Command="{Binding DataContext.ShowFilterCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" 
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                                    >
                                    <Button.ContentTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <Image Source="/Images/filter.png" Width="10" Height="10" />
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </Button.ContentTemplate>
                                </Button>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Field">
        <DataGrid 
            x:Name="FielsdViewDataGrid" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredFieldViewItems}" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            IsReadOnly="True"
            CanUserReorderColumns="True"
            CanUserResizeColumns="True"
            CanUserSortColumns="True"
            >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn 
                    Header="Class"
                    Binding="{Binding ClassName}" 
                    >
                    <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                                <Button 
                                    Name="buttonFieldViewClassFilter" 
                                    Margin="10,0,0,0"
                                    Command="{Binding DataContext.ShowFilterCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" 
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                                    >
                                    <Button.ContentTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <Image Source="/Images/filter.png" Width="10" Height="10" />
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </Button.ContentTemplate>
                                </Button>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

---

## Original Version

It turns out that OP has multiple filtered columns per grid, so the solution below won't work: The command needs to know not just which grid, but which column in the grid. `DataGridColumn` isn't in the visual tree so we can't use that `x:Name` for the command parameter. We could use `{RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridColumnHeader}` and write a converter that returns `DataGridColumnHeader.Column.Binding.Path.Path` -- but both grids have columns named `ClassName`. Next up is a multibinding that passes that ancestor, and also the grid itself. Since OP's original solution involved distinct content per column header anyway, I decided to do it the easy but verbose way, with multiple templates.

**I made one important change that will affect your code:** Since the header content for both DataGrid columns is now being created by the same template, the name of the button is now the same for both. Therefore, `CommandParameter` is now bound to the name of the `DataGrid`.

```
<TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="175" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="716" Margin="10,0,0,0">
    <TabControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="FilterColumnHeaderTemplate">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                <Button 
                    Name="buttonClassFilter" 
                    Margin="10,0,0,0"
                    Command="{Binding DataContext.ShowFilterCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" 
                    CommandParameter="{Binding Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"
                    >
                    <Button.ContentTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Rectangle Fill="DeepSkyBlue" Width="10" Height="10" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Button.ContentTemplate>
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.Resources>
    <TabItem Header="Class">
        <DataGrid 
            x:Name="ClassViewDataGrid" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredClassViewItems}" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            IsReadOnly="True"
            CanUserReorderColumns="True"
            CanUserResizeColumns="True"
            CanUserSortColumns="True"
            >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn 
                    Header="Class"
                    Binding="{Binding ClassName}" 
                    HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource FilterColumnHeaderTemplate}" 
                    />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Field">
        <DataGrid 
            x:Name="FielsdViewDataGrid" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredFieldViewItems}" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            IsReadOnly="True"
            CanUserReorderColumns="True"
            CanUserResizeColumns="True"
            CanUserSortColumns="True"
            >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn
                    Header="Class"
                    Binding="{Binding ClassName}" 
                    HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource FilterColumnHeaderTemplate}" 
                    />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

If you want to vary the header content between the columns in the two different DataGrids, you can do that with bindings or create a second template if necessary.

You could have also [done this with a `BindingProxy`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24452264/424129) created in `TabControl.Resources`, but binding proxies are a last-ditch kludge that we use when there's no "correct" way to do something. In this case, the "correct" way is easy and direct and perfectly satisfactory.

Comment: Would it also work to bind to something that's a parent to both items, such as the `TabControl` itself? The DataGrid isn't created at the time the binding is evaluated, however the TabControl should be.

Comment: @Rachel That didn't work. The visual tree chain from the header content to the TabControl leads through the DataGrid -- if that doesn't exist yet, you're out of luck. `ElementName=MyTabControl` didn't work either (I didn't forget to give the TabControl that name!), perhaps also because they're not in the same visual tree. In OP's original XAML, the `StackPanel` inside `DataGridTextColumn.Header` is the event horizon at the time the binding tries to resolve.

Comment: Ahh ok, good to know. I know I've had issues in the past with databindings in the column headers because they don't seem to inherit the DataContext the same way other controls would. Nice to know of this solution though :)

Comment: @EdPlunkett  OK. Thanks for the complete answer. but I want each PopUp to have a different content, that' s why I ve taken the name of the button in my C# code.. to know which button I've clicked and fill the list correspondingly. Can I obtain this aspect now ?

Comment: That's why I need to identify on which button I have clicked

Comment: @Nica I told you how to do that. The name of the grids differ too.

Comment: @EdPlunkett ok, but how to access the name of the column throught the grids' name ? the thing is that in each tabItem I have multiple columns, not only one per tabItem

Comment: @Nica Ok, that changes things. Try naming the columns themselves and going by that. If that fails, create one template per column. I’ll be at the office in an hour.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I've tried to include the dataTemplate part from your example in each column but it doesn't go ok.. the problem is that if I include a button for each column, the second tabItem is not displayed

Comment: @Nica I tested my example. I'd have to see your new XAML to figure out what you're doing differently. In a few minutes I'm updating my answer with the two options I've come up with to allow you to have a command parameter per column.

Comment: @Nica Are you using C#7?

Comment: @EdPlunkett  Yes.. can you reedit your XAML please ? I don t know how to correctly update each button for each column in order to second tabItem be visible

Comment: @Nica That makes no sense at all. My XAML works perfectly. I can't even begin to guess what I would change in order to create the problem you're describing. All I can do is show you how to do it right, and I already did that. Show me your new XAML or I can't help you.

Comment: @Nica See update. I suggest you create a separate HeaderTemplate for each column. This is very much like your original solution and it works.

Comment: @EdPlunkett what I've missed was that I've wrote <DataGridTextColumn.Header> instead of <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>. But thanks a lot!

Comment: @Nica Ahh, excellent. I figured it had to be something simple like that. See my last update: This can be done with a single template.