# Bind to ViewModel from ContextMenu in ListBox Item

Tags: wpf, binding

I have a ViewModel with a command 'OpenCommand', a flag 'IsConextMenuVisible' and an observable list 'Links'.

```
public ObservableList<string> Links { get; set; }
public bool IsContextMenuVisible { get; set; }
public ICommand OpenCommand { get; set; }
```

in XAML i want the following to work.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Links}">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding}">
        <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
           <ContextMenu Visibility="{Binding IsContextMenuVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibiltyHiddenConverter}}">
             <MenuItem Header="Open" Command="{Binding OpenCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
           </ContextMenu>
        </Textblock.ContextMenu>
      </TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I've already tried some binding expressions for the inner bindings on the ContextMenu, but nothing seems to work. Something like:

```
Visibility="{Binding Path=DataContext.IsContextMenuVisible,
             Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityCollapsedConverter},
             RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is "problematic" as the kids say because the context menu isn't in the visual tree, so no flavor of `RelativeSource` is going to work.

You can often bind to properties of `PlacementTarget`, but in this case you need a visual ancestor of the `PlacementTarget`, and `RelativeSource` won't do an ancestor of something else.

In WPF, when there's a gap in the visual tree, the last ditch option is always a BindingProxy. Here's what that class looks like (including the URL of the StackOverflow question I stole it from -- that class has been copied and pasted around many, many questions and answers on this site):

```
//  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24452264/bindingproxy-binding-to-the-indexed-property
public class BindingProxy : Freezable
{
    #region Overrides of Freezable

    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    {
        return new BindingProxy();
    }

    #endregion

    public object Data
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(DataProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Data.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(object), typeof(BindingProxy), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

And you would use it like this. First create the BindingProxy as a resource, in a location where it can "see" the desired element:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:BoolToVisibiltyHiddenConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibiltyHiddenConverter" />

    <!-- {Binding} with no path will be the window's datacontext, the main viewmodel. -->
    <local:BindingProxy Data="{Binding}" x:Key="MainViewModelBindingProxy" />
</Window.Resources>
```

And then use it for the `Source` of the binding. The desired DataContext will be the `Data` property of the proxy object, so provide paths relative to `Data`:

```
<TextBlock.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu 
        Visibility="{Binding Data.IsContextMenuVisible, 
            Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibiltyHiddenConverter}, 
             Source={StaticResource MainViewModelBindingProxy}}"
        >
        <MenuItem 
            Header="Open" 
            Command="{Binding OpenCommand}" 
            CommandParameter="{Binding}"
            />
    </ContextMenu>
</TextBlock.ContextMenu>
```

**Now you've got another problem:** The menu is still popping up. It just doesn't happen to be visible. If the user right clicks, it'll pop up invisibly, and suddenly appear when `IsContextMenuVisible` changes to true. That's not what you want.

You could omit the converter and just bind directly to `ContextMenu.IsEnabled`: It'll still pop up, but it'll be grayed out. This is consistent with common Windows UI practice.

You could also have a style trigger so that the TextBlock only has a ContextMenu when you want it to have one. Because that trigger is on the TextBlock, it's in the visual tree we can use a conventional RelativeSource for the binding.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding}">
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger 
                    Binding="{Binding Data.IsContextMenuVisible, 
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}}"
                    Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ContextMenu >
                                <MenuItem 
                                    Header="Open" 
                                    Command="{Binding OpenCommand}" 
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                                    />
                            </ContextMenu>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!