# Visual UI Automation Verify shows DisconnectedItem in ContextMenu (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, contextmenu, ui-automation

Stackoverflow.

I've looked through a good amount of questions\answers, and still not found the clue to the issue I'm facing in Visual UI Automation Verify (2.0).

I have a ContextMenu in TreeList (DevExpress control):

```
<dxg:TreeListControl.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu x:Name="TreeListContextMenu" DataContext="{Binding Path=Data, Source={StaticResource Proxy}}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Data.SelectedItemContextMenuItemCollection, Source={StaticResource Proxy}}"/>
            </dxg:TreeListControl.ContextMenu>
```

I have a simple binding proxy, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24452264/bindingproxy-binding-to-the-indexed-property) declared with the following code:

```
<dataStructures:BindingProxy x:Key="Proxy" Data="{Binding}" />
```

DataContext of the User Control and DataContext of the ContextMenu are bound to Data property on the proxy (because ContextMenu doesn't belong to the same visual tree).

In the non-shared MenuItem style I'm assigning the value from Data property of the proxy to the attached property of the MenuItem:

```
<Setter Property="helpers:ParentControlDataContextBindingHelper.ParentControlDataContext" Value="{Binding Path=Data, Source={StaticResource Proxy}}" />
```

The reason it's done this way:

In the tree there are various objects. Each object might have different ContextMenu item list based on object's certain property value. I'm handling the "ContextMenuOpening" event by routing it to the Command:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="ContextMenuOpening">
                            <prism:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ContextMenuOpeningCommand}"/>
                        </i:EventTrigger>
<i:Interaction.Triggers/>
```

In ContextMenuOpeningCommand command I'm clearing and then filling up SelectedItemContextMenuItemCollection (which consists of MenuItem Visual Models - binding sources for Header, Command and Icon for the MenuItem) based on the property of the SelectedItem

When the context menu is called the first time - it appears on Visual UI Automation Verify (with the correct ContextMenuItem headers), but it can't be tested after it is closed - its contents in Visual UI Automation Verify are DisconnnectedItems. If I call next ContextMenu on the different type of element and the list of ContextMenu items is different - Visual UI Automation Verify doesn't show even headers of the menu items (the headers are empty because DataContext of menu item is DisconnectedItem after menu closes). If I'm using "hardcoded" ContextMenu with all bindings and items in XAML - everything is ok.

I'm not sure if this behavior is actually by design or not. Is it possible to test ContextMenu with non-static items collection with Visual UI Automation Verify? Inspect.exe in WindowsKits behaves the same way. What's more important - how I can get around that to be able to test the menu with VisualUIAVerify?