# WPF xaml Bindable Variable

Tags: wpf, xaml

Example: I have a form that can perform some work.
While the work is done i need to hide some UI elements.

What I do now is set the converter for each element that I need to be hidden:

```
<Button1 ..      Visibility="{Binding Executing, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityInversed}}"/>
<TextBlock2 ..   Visibility="{Binding Executing, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityInversed}}"/>
<CancelButton .. Visibility="{Binding Executing, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}"/>
```

What I would like to have is some kind of variable in xaml to assign once and be able to bind to:
(pseudo code. doesn't work)

```
<!-- The Variables -->
<Visibility Name="VisibleWhileExecuting" Value="{Binding Executing, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}" />
<Visibility Name="HiddenWhileExecuting"  Value="{Binding Executing, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityInversed}}" />

<!-- The Elements -->
<Button1 ..      Visibility="{Binding HiddenWhileExecuting}"/>
<TextBlock2 ..   Visibility="{Binding HiddenWhileExecuting}"/>
<CancelButton .. Visibility="{Binding VisibleWhileExecuting}"/>
```

Is there a way to do so?

---

Update:

What I have come up to is creating two icons displaying the work status. Then I can bind to that icon's visibility.

something like this (didn't check)

```
<Image Name="ExecutingIcon" .. Visibility="{Binding Executing, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}"/>
<Image Name="IdleIcon" ..      Visibility="{Binding Executing, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityInversed}}"/>

<Button1 ..      Visibility="{Binding ElementName=IdleIcon, Path=Visibility}" />
<CancelButton .. Visibility="{Binding ElementName=ExecutingIcon, Path=Visibility}"/>
```

Comment: BindingProxy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24452264/bindingproxy-binding-to-the-indexed-property - not related issue, but shows BindingProxy implementation

Comment: or CalcBinding : https://stackoverflow.com/a/61550165/1506454

Comment: Why don't you simply set the source property? Why would you need any additional variable?

Comment: mm8, didn't really get what you mean. How can the source property help here?

Answer (score 0):

If you are manually setting the boolean values, then you can directly use

```
Visibility HiddenWhileExecuting;
Visibility VisibleWhileExecuting;
```

instead of boolean values, which you can bind directly and need not send it to converter.

You can handle the visibility in the C# code as follows

```
HiddenWhileExecuting = Visibility.Hidden;
```

Comment: This will work. I just didn't want to add extra properties to my datasource class.